# The named parameter 'auth' is required, but there's no corresponding argument

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, recaptcha

i tried everything with firebase but not able to resolve this error please help.

[ss for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HelBR.png)

```
RecaptchaVerifier(
          size: RecaptchaVerifierSize.compact,
          theme: RecaptchaVerifierTheme.dark,
          onSuccess: (){

            print('reCAPTCHA Completed!');

            if(!resend){
              nextPosition();
            }

            setState(() {
              _showResend = false;
            });
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the field `auth` to the `RecaptchaVerifier` widget.

Comment: how can we do that?